# Filtering several numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get some data froma Oracle DB to Power QUery (Excel).
I am managing this with a sql-statement. 
There are 10 columns (50 total) and millions of rows. I need to filter some data / columns. The criterie are just some numbers like:
100258
100256
100333
100055

This are just SAP-Cost center

For now I have just a Where-statment, which includes 22 different numbers.

```
WHERE column1 = 100256,
      column1 = 100258, ....
```

Is there maybe a more elegant way?
Maybe something like an array?

best regards
Joshua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `WHERE IN` e.g.

```
WHERE column1 IN(100256, 100258, ...)
```

If you expect to have more values than can be supported by `IN` (1000, I think) then consider creating a table to store the values, say `table1` with a column `val`.  Then you could use:

```
WHERE column1 IN (SELECT val FROM table1)
```

You might also consider joining to `table1`, depending on what your actual query is.

Comment: WOuld be a Join maybe more appropriated for values >1000?

Comment: @joshua1990 Yes you are right.  The thing is, the OP did not show an actual query.  Honestly, you might want to use a table even if you more than say 20 values, just for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Use with clause:

```
 With numbers as (
 Select 100256,100258 As number From dual
 )

 From table1,numbers
 Where column1 = numbers.number
```